# Paramiko error "bound method ChannelFile.read of <paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 0 (open) window=2097152 "

Tags: python, paramiko

While running the below script, I get the transport error.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import paramiko
print("hello world")
ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('host_IP',username='user',password='passwd')
cmd='/usr/lib/qlogic/qmgr-ui'
print(cmd)
stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command(cmd)
z=stdout.read
print(z)
ssh.close()
```

Error is :

```
<bound method ChannelFile.read of <paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 0 (open) window=2097152 -> <paramiko.Transport at 0xac44ff28 (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 1 open channel(s))>>>>
```

For the other service `/usr/lib/qlogic/qmgr`, it works properly but for the `qmgr-ui` service its not working.
Can someone please help me out ?

Thanks,
Nikhil.

Comment: Can you call /usr/lib/qlogic/qmgr successfully in the command line?

Comment: Yes...I can execute the /usr/lib/qlogic/qmgr-ui from command line.

Answer (score 2):

the problem was with the "read" statement

Should have been:
`z=stdout.read()`